# A book about pocket universes

Tags: story-identification

Long time ago I have read a book where the pocket universe can be created for free and the main hero travel from one universe to other to find someone.

One thing that I also recall is a universe, where the time is stopped and they use some thing to make the time go around the wearer.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "long time ago"? 5 yrs? 20 yrs? What language / country did you read this in?

Comment: Aside from the time part, could be [World of Tiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_of_Tiers)?

Answer (score 4):

That reminds me of ["Chronomaster"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronomaster) a script for computer game started by Roger Zelazny and finised by Jane Lindskold after his death. The script was novelized and publised as a book in 1996. Plot revolves around famous pocket universe desighner, who must restore several universes from temporal stasis. He uses something that creates a bubble of normal timeflow around him as he travels "freezed" universes.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to put this on here because it jumped in my mind first, and it sort of fits your description..."a Wrinkle in Time" by Madeleine L'Engle. They have a device called a Tesseract which allows them to travel to other universes in order to find someone. (see Wikipedia page) Sorry if this doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Implied Spaces? I was searching for this book, stumbled upon this page, maybe it's the same?

Comment: We don't mind "bumping" old questions, but added detail would be appreciated; what about this book matches with the OP's memory? Plot summaries and/or quotes would be helpful